# Dynamic Button getting out of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-relativelayout

I am developing an application in which I am using `Drag and Drop` functionality.
In that I am generating buttons `OnClick`.The code is working fine but when I `drag` the `button` to the corners of the `relativelayout`,button gets out of the `layout`. I want it to stay inside of the `layout`.
I am sharing my code and image both. From the image you can understand my problem clearly

[image]

Thanks in advance.!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    Button btnAddButton;
    RelativeLayout rl1;
    int i = 1;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;
    ViewGroup _root;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        _root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        btnAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                add(v);

            }
        });
    }
    public void add(View v) {
        Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        //btn.setId(i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int a=(int) (Math.random()*100);
       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(Math.random()*100), 1).show();//double a=Math.random();
        layoutParam.leftMargin = 30+a;

        if (i > 1) {

            layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (i - 1));
        }

        btn.setText("Button" + i);
        rl1.addView(btn, layoutParam);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
        i++;
    } 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
            }
            _root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="AddButton"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAdd" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don´t know where the problem is, but I had a similar one with using the onTouchListener only. I had success by using onDragListener instead. Here is an example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/

Comment: That is completely a different code buddy..

Comment: when I drag the button to the corner it get hides and my requirement is to set some conditions so that button does not get hide

Comment: I know, but using onDragListener will give You more efficient and secure way to handle what You want. This was just an example of how to do it. Yes I know, it´s hard to rewrite the code, but using OnDragListener will give You a more satisfying result.

Comment: okk I'm trying your link @Opiatefuchs

Comment: The other thing is see is, that Your RelativeLayout where You put the buttons inside is set to wrap_content. I don´t think that this layout is realizing really when something is changed like a button drop. Try to set it to match_parent, if possible.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs no buddy its not helping